# Laravel 5.2 Push onto deeper indexed arrays within a Collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-collection

Is there a way to put/merge on changes to a deeper index on a collection without converting the collection to an array first?

I have a $collection with 4 indices that all contain $arrays so in order to push onto the arrays I have to do this:

```
$collection = $collection->toArray(); // without this get array_push parameter 1 should be an array object given error
array_push($collection[$index], $array);
```

But, I was hoping there was a better way so I didn't have to re-collect(...) the original $collection before moving on, something like below, which I know wouldn't work, but forms an example of something less awkward then above:

```
$collection->get($index)->merge($array);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I put in temporarily using array_push above didn't merge the array with an existing array, but this does work and seem a bit more elegant.  Thanks to Marcin Nabialek who pointed out that Collections implement the ArrayAccess interface, which didn't solve the use of array_push, but was used in the answer below to override the exist array with the changes.

```
$collection[$index] = collect($collection->get($key))->merge($array);
```

I'm open to any improvements to push my use of Collections.

Answer (score 1):

As collections implements `ArrayAccess` interface, instead of:

```
$collection = $collection->toArray();
array_push($collection[$index], $array);
```

you can use:

```
array_push($collection[$index], $array);
```

**EDIT**

Okay, the code won't work because you get error that you cannot assign overloaded properties, but you mentioned also other error in comment.

Assume you have collection like this:

```
$collection = collect([[1,2],[11,12],[21,22],[31,32]]);
```

and you want to append `13` to `[11,12]`.

You can do it like this:

```
$collection->put(1, array_merge($collection[1], [13]));
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that :)  I had some sort of error originally mentioning that $collection was an object so I just assumed I couldn't access it like an array

Comment: It looks like I'm still getting that error when I try to use array_push `[2016-08-24 16:40:03] local.ERROR: ErrorException: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in /home/vagrant/project/app/Http/Controllers/EventController.php:282
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'array_push() ex...', '/home/vagrant/s...', 282, Array)
#1 /home/vagrant/project/app/Http/Controllers/EventController.php(282): array_push(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection), Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection))`

Comment: Nice, that is a pretty clean solution.  Thanks

Comment: Only issue is array_merge doesn't like $collection[$index] it says it's not an array - `[2016-08-25 16:52:48] local.ERROR: ErrorException: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in /home/vagrant/project/app/Http/Controllers/EventController.php:334`

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy using [**put**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-put)

`$collection->put($index, $array);`

That's it

If you want to push to the end of collection use [**push**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-push)

`$collection->push($array);`